# Laravel Baum path to Node

Tags: php, laravel, nested-sets

I have a Page model, this model contains a Slug field. Is it possible to get the path to the nodes? ( root/page1/sub1/ )

I need the Paths for my Navigation, the Query looks like:

```
$pages = Page::first()->getDescendants()->toHierarchy();
```

and the Result:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="/root">root</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/root/page1">page1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/root/page1/sub1">sub1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/root/page1/sub2">sub2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/root/page2">page2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/root/page2/sub1">sub1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/root/page2/sub2">sub2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/root/page3">page3</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the path to your node:

```
SELECT ancestor.*
FROM category as child, category as ancestor 
WHERE child.lft >= ancestor.lft AND child.lft <= ancestor.rgt 
AND child.id = YOUR_CHILD_ID
ORDER BY ancestor.lft
```